# Using IF and ISBLANK statement to determine a range of cells if all of them have information in them

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to figure out how to write a statement in excel 
If any 3 cells are blank : induction 1, induction 2, induction 3
then another cell will be blank
If All contain text will say "complete"

```
=IF(OR(AND(ISBLANK(General!E4), ISBLANK(General!F4), (ISBLANK(General!G4)),"","Complete")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the opposite approach, if counting the number of cells that are not blank is `3` then return "complete, else return ""

```
=IF(COUNTA(E4:G4)=3,"complete","")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i did try something similar with count-blank but didn't work, knew i wasn't far off :)